# I'm keep getting an error that says the column of the range is too small

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I was writing some code and when i tried to run it I got an error

> The starting column of the range is too small.

I'm using Google Apps Script

The error I'm getting is on this line

```
var cellCup = ss.getRange(ctCup, 0).activate().getValue();
```

```
const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(THIS).getSheetByName('WP_Data');
var ctCup =114;
var cellCup = ss.getRange(ctCup, 0).activate().getValue();
```

But it works here

```
    var ctMHS = 3;
    var cellMHS = ss.getRange('A3');
    while ( cellMHS.offset(ctMHS, 0).getValue() != "" ) {
      ctMHS++;
    }
```

Comment: Does getRange take a '0' based index or does it start from 1?

Comment: its starts from row 114 and column 0

Comment: getRange starts with row 1, column 1

Comment: How can I start from row ctCup and column 1 in that case?

Comment: By the way, `.activate()` is unnecessary: you can just do `ss.getRange(ctCup, 0).getValue();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Google App Script docs https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column

`The column index of the cell to return; column indexing starts with 1.`

This should fix your problem:

```
var cellCup = ss.getRange(ctCup, 1).activate().getValue();
```

Comment: But do you know why it works in that case?   I edited my question

Comment: The index is not zero based in a sheet. That means that 1 depicts the first row/column in it. The `ss.getRange('A3');` is called a1 Notation and in the docs is explained here: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangea1notation

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Kostas, the column and row indices for `.getRange()` should start at 1.

The reason this snippet works with a 0 index:

```
cellMHS.offset(ctMHS, 0).getValue()
```

is that the `.offset()` method is different from the `.getRange()` method: `.offset()` doesn't expect an absolute cell or row index: its arguments are offsets *relative* to the range represented by `cellMHS`, i.e. how far away from that range.  So a value of 0 just means use the same column as the original range.  You can even pass a negative offset to reference a column to the left of `cellMHS`.

Comment: yeah that makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Visual Studio Code try to reopen the Program because it happened to me to so its kinda of a glitch.

Comment: I'm using google app script

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).